# How to recall a function in a function?

Tags: javascript

This script was placed in my forms between divs for captcha. what should I do to refresh the particular div to recall the function with refresh button (not refresh the whole form).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);       
    var c = a + b
    function mathCap()
    {
        document.write("What is "+ a + " + " + b +"? ");
   /*     document.write("<input id='numsCap' type='text' maxlength='4' size='4'/>"); */
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to do? What element will call the event listener?

Answer (score 1):

On the head of the document create a function that has the functionality that you need and put it on the "onclick" event of your refresh button.

```
<head>

function mathCap()
{
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);       
    var c = a + b

    var q = "What is "+ a + " + " + b +"? "

    // Code to set The InnerHTML property of the div.
    document.getElementById('id of the div').InnerHTML = q;

}

</head>
```

Comment: Thanks sir.. can i create onclick event like this <input type="button" onClick="click()">refresh</input>

Comment: <input type="button" onClick="name_of_header_function()" value="Refresh"/>

Comment: id of the div unable to find sir..pl help

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mathCap()
{
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);       
    var c = a + b

    var q = "What is "+ a + " + " + b +"? "

    // Code to set The InnerHTML property of the div.
    document.getElementById('rand_question').innerHTML = q;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="mathCap()">
<div id="rand_question"></div>
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="mathCap()"/>
</body>
</html>
<!-- Copy paste in file.html -->

Comment: Thaks. It works in HTML. But my code in JSP. hence div id "value" not printing. I tried with span id. That is also not printing. And i can't use onload also. when i use call the fuction as function mathCap() it is printing on the form. But i am unable to get the Id to refresh..